# Jackson Faster XML AJAX Submit not working properly @JsonBackReference, @JsonManagedReference

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jackson

So I'm using Spring Boot and I'm trying to submit a form using AJAX, and I'm getting an error in my console in Eclipse (STS), and in the Chrome console, however the data is submitting just fine, but it's not following through with the ajax because I tell the page to reload as soon I submit but nothing happens when I click the submit button.  When I check in my MySQL database everything is submitted and mapped the way I want and when I refresh the browser the data I submitted shows up.

I'm trying to add a comment to a post and assign that comment to the user object. I'll show you guys my code so you can see what I'm talking about.

So Here's my user object, which I have mapped with a @OneToMany annotation along with @JsonManaged annotation.

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="user")
@JsonManagedReference
@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowGetters=true, value = "user" )
public Set<Comment> getComments() {
  return comments;
}
```

I also have this at the top of the user object

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class User
```

Here's my Comment object

```
@ManyToOne
@JsonBackReference
@JsonIgnoreProperties(allowGetters=true, value = "comments")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

Along with this

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class Comment
```

Here's my AJAX, some of the code is to allow it to work with Thymeleaf, in case you're unfamiliar.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">

        /*<![CDATA[*/

        var postId = /*[[${post.id}]]*/'1';

        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");

        $(document).ajaxSend(function(e, xhr, options) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        });

        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").on("click", function(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url : "newComment",
                type : "post",
                data : {
                    "postId" : postId,
                    "newComment" : $("#newComment").val()
                },
                success : function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    location.reload();
                },
                error : function() {
                    console.log("There was an error");
                }

            });
        });
      });
    /*]]>*/

</script>
```

Here's my controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="viewCourse/post/newComment", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody Post newComment (@Valid @RequestParam Long postId, @RequestParam String newComment, ModelMap model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user)
{
Post post = postRepo.findOne(postId);
Comment comment = new Comment();
comment.setComment(newComment);
comment.setPost(post);

comment.setUser(user);
user.getComments().add(comment);

comment.setUser(user);

post.getComments().add(comment);
Post savedPost = postRepo.save(post);

return savedPost;
}
```

And Here's part of the error I get in my Eclipse (STS) Console, it's pretty long so I didn't think I should post the whole thing.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties.allowGetters()Z
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findPropertiesToIgnore(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:126) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.createContextual(BeanSerializerBase.java:424) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.handleSecondaryContextualization(SerializerProvider.java:944) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:495) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.PropertySerializerMap.findAndAddSecondarySerializer(PropertySerializerMap.java:90) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase._findAndAddDynamic(AsArraySerializerBase.java:321) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:144) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase._serializeWithObjectId(BeanSerializerBase.java:597) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase._serializeWithObjectId(BeanSerializerBase.java:597) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serializeContents(CollectionSerializer.java:149) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:111) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.CollectionSerializer.serialize(CollectionSerializer.java:24) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:157) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase._serializeWithObjectId(BeanSerializerBase.java:597) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:693) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:675) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase._serializeWithObjectId(BeanSerializerBase.java:597) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:148) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:130) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter$Prefetch.serialize(ObjectWriter.java:1387) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValue(ObjectWriter.java:889) ~[jackson-databind-2.6.3.jar:2.6.3]
```

If anyone can see why this is acting strange and could let me know that would be awesome.  Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Here's my Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.coderscampus</groupId>
<artifactId>Quizbanks3</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Quizbanks3</name>
<description>CourseCreation project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>springloaded</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>        
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--Thymeleaf Spring Security-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.hateoas</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

       <repositories>
          <repository>
              <id>spring-releases</id>
              <name>Spring Releases</name>
              <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
          </repository>
      </repositories>

      <pluginRepositories>
          <pluginRepository>
              <id>spring-releases</id>
              <name>Spring Releases</name>
              <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
          </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Comment: What version of `jackson-core` are you using? btw. I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but usually using only one of the annotations from `@JsonIdentityInfo` `@JsonManagedReference` `@JsonIgnoreProperties` is enough.

Comment: I'm not sure, spring boot says `Overriding managed version 2.6.3 for jackson-
 databind`, whenever I put a version, so I was just leaving it empty

Comment: can you show your pom or build.gradle?

Comment: I just added the pom to the question

Comment: well, seems like `jackson-annotations` should be 2.6.3 which should work fine. I suggest you either manually specify 2.6.3 for `jackson-annotations`, or just make sure that it's 2.6.3. If it doesn't work, you could try removing `JsonIgnoreProperties`, i'm not sure you need it when you have `@JsonIdentityInfo` and `@JsonManagedReference`

Comment: I've tried both, and it still doesn't work

Comment: Well it works, but I have to refresh the page, and it's supposed to do an automatic refresh